# SSH-проксирование

Tags: ssh

В текущей инфраструктуре существует docker-контейнер с gitlab, к которому надо прокинуть ssh-доступ из машины-хоста, т.е. предполагается примерно такое взаимодействие:

- ssh root@host: обычный вход
- ssh git@host: прием произвольного сертификата, затем проксирование подключения к git@localhost:10022 с тем сертификатом, с которым обратился клиент. Для клиента это должно выглядеть как обычное подключение.

Как организовать подобную архитектуру?

Comment: *как организовать?* — если под «сертификатом» подразумевался публичный ключ, то, в изложенном виде, насколько мне известно — никак.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, публичный ключ

Comment: Т.е. настройка agent forwarding на клиенте не приемлема? Подключение должно быть абсолютно прозрачным?

Comment: @kmv я не очень силен в терминологии, если agent forwarding - запрос на использование того же ключа в последующих подключениях на серверной стороне, то, конечно, хотелось бы этого избежать, но вообще - приемлемо.

Comment: @Etki это подразумевает запуск у каждого пользователя перед подключением программы ssh-agent и определенные параметры для ssh (либо правка конфига). Пробросом ключей занимается как раз ssh agent, другим способом, насколько мне известно, пробросить ключ нельзя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представленный метод не совсем соответствует вашим требованиям, но другим способом пробросить ключ, по-видимому, нельзя. Подключение будет перенаправлено на второй сервис, аутентификация на нем пройдет автоматически по тому же ключу, но перед подключением пользователю придется произвести дополнительные действия.

**На стороне сервера**:

В файле `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` добавляем следующие строки, которые осуществляют немедленное переподключение ко второму ssh-сервису сразу после логина пользователя git (на других пользователей не действует):

```
Match User git
   ForceCommand ssh git@localhost -p 10022
```

На сервере host должен существовать пользователь git с заполненным `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

**На стороне пользователя**:

Необходимо перед подключением у пользователя запустить программу `ssh-agent` (командой `` eval `ssh-agent` ``) и добавить в нее ключ командой `ssh-add`. Затем пользователь подключается к вашему серверу командой

```
ssh -A username@host
```

Параметр `-А` включает проброс ключа, `username` - это `root` или `git` в вашем случае. Пока ssh-agent висит в памяти, проброс будет работать. Проброс на второй сервис выполнится прозрачно и незаметно для пользователя.

Также можно поправить конфиг `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` у пользователя, чтобы каждый раз не указывать ключ `-A`:

```
Host *
   ForwardAgent yes
```

Comment: вероятно, стоит уточнить, какому именно из требований этот вариант не удовлетворяет: «приём произвольного ключа».